# database error in dbt snapshot, clause must target a hash distributed table

Tags: azure-synapse, snapshot, dbt

I am getting stuck, does anyone knows how to solve the error? I am using dbt-synapse. Highly appreciated for your help.

dbt snapshot errored out on the second run.

```sql
{% snapshot ABC_Incr %}
    {{
        config(
            target_schema='A_publish',
            strategy='check',
            check_cols='all',
            unique_key='ID',
        )
    }}
    SELECT * FROM {{ ref('ABC_Conf')}}
{% endsnapshot %}
```

```
14:27:02  Completed with 1 error and 0 warnings:
14:27:02  
14:27:02  Database Error in snapshot ABC_Incr (snapshots/ABC_Incr.sql)
14:27:02    ('42000', '\[42000\] \[Microsoft\]\[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server\]\[SQL Server\]Merge statements with a WHEN NOT MATCHED \[BY TARGET\] clause must target a hash distributed table. (100087) (SQLExecDirectW)')
14:27:02    compiled Code at target/run/test1/snapshots/ABC_Incr.sql
14:27:02
```

No clue on how to solve the issue.

Comment: I solved the error by adding additional configs of index and distribution. Is there a easier way to do so?

index='CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX', dist='HASH([ID])'